# Replicating glTranslate

Tags: function, opengl, translation

I need to come up with a function similar to `glTranslate` to know how things work. I've read that glTranslate parameters supply the x, y, z coordinates by which matrix is translated. I'm supposed to relate it to the translation formula:

x' = x + tx; t = translation factor

So is this correct?

new matrix = current matrix + ((transformation coordinates  x, y, z)*current matrix)

The current matrix is taken care by the `glMatrixMode` correct? And as for the multiplication, I assume this involves `glMultMatrix` but do how I achieve this given `glMultMatrix` has a constant as parameter and `glTranslate` provide coordinates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So is this correct?
>   new matrix = current matrix + ((transformation coordinates x, y, z)*current matrix)

No.

The correct implementation is

```
M' = M · T
```

where

```
    | 1 0 0 x |
    | 0 1 0 y |
T = | 0 0 1 z |
    | 0 0 0 1 |
```

> The current matrix is taken care by the glMatrixMode correct?

Yes

> And as for the multiplication, I assume this involves `glMultMatrix`

In the actual OpenGL driver code probably not, but semantically yes

> But do how I achieve this given glMultMatrix has a constant as parameter

For the call `glMultMatrix(T)`, OpenGL performs the operation

```
M' = M · T
```

So all what you have to do is creating a translation matrix T like shown above (be aware the OpenGL is column major, so it looks "transposed" in the code) and pass that to `glMultiMatrix`.

```
GLfloat T[16] = {
    1, 0, 0, 0,
    0, 1, 0, 0,
    0, 0, 1, 0,
    x, y, z, 1 };

glMultMatrixf(T);
```

However you shouldn't use the old fixed function pipeline and the OpenGL matrix manipulation methods at all. OpenGL is not a very good math library. Better use something like GLM or Eigen or linmath.h and self defined `mat4` shader uniforms; or if you insist on using fixed function use `glLoadMatrix` to load readily prepared matrices.

Comment: What did you mean by fixed function pipeline? The gl_ references? And is the `glLoadMatrix` the same as GLfloat T[16] you provided? It would change as necessary for, say, scale and rotate, right? Accordingly based on the scale and rotate matrices.

Comment: @AtikahMohamad: Fixed function is everything **not** involving shaders. Also in compatibility mode certain fixed function state is reflected by built in variables names `gl_…`available in the shaders. I recommend not using them, it makes your programs harder to polish up for modern render paths. glLoadMatrix will just copy the matrix as you provide it and overwrite whatever is currently on top of the currently selected (glMatrixMode) matrix stack.

Comment: Fixed function and shaders are very new to me. I'll look up to better understand them. Thank you for the pointers.